# Symfony2 - "no association"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm still trying to work with joins in Symfony2 and Doctrine.

So far I got this:

**controller**

```
    $ownRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('GameShelfUsersBundle:Ownership');

    $ownQuery = $ownRepo->createQueryBuilder('own')
        ->leftJoin('own.games','g', 'WITH', 'g.id = own.game')
        ->where('own.user = :user')
        ->andWhere('own.own = :type')
        ->setParameters(array(
        'user' => $user,
        'type' => $type
    ))
        ->orderBy('own.updated','desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

**Ownership entity (bottom)** - since it's long - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jrxc7FXF).

I'm getting errors when I try to run the controller:

```
QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 79 near 'g WITH g.id =': Error: Class GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\Ownership has no association named games

QueryException: SELECT own FROM GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\Ownership own LEFT JOIN own.games g WITH g.id = own.game WHERE own.user = :user AND own.own = :type ORDER BY own.updated desc
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Most likely this is because you are mixing yml and annotation mappings. And since you have both `games` and `game`, you probably have the relation mixed up in this case.

Comment: Life would be much easier if you would use Many-to-One Relationships and let doctrine do the work for you.

Comment: Drop the WITH stuff on your leftJoin.  All you need is: ->leftJoin('own.games','g')  D2 is smart enough to figure out the details.  And of course your Ownership entity needs a games relation defined.  Unless it's a x to 1 relation then change games to game.